# Error on declaring an array of structures

Tags: c

I have to declare an array of structures of size 16. The following code gives an error
code1.c:12:1: error: initializer element is not constant

```
typedef struct node 
{
int tokenvalue;
struct  node *next;
char *n;
} node;
node *dummy=(node *)malloc(26*sizeof(node));
```

Also using node dummy[26] gives segmentation fault. What should I do?

Comment: size of 16, but using `26*sizeof`?

Comment: If you intend to use `dummy[26]`, what you should do is allocate at least `(27*sizeof(node)` chars. Regarding your error, the line number falls outside the snippet you have provided, so how are we supposed to help?

Comment: i want an array of 26 structures, hence 26

Comment: The error is in node *dummy=(node *)malloc(26*sizeof(node));

Comment: and then you access the 27th, `dummy[26]`.

Comment: Arrays in C are numbered starting at zero, so the 26 elements of a 26-element array are node[0] through node[25].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't initialize objects having static storage with anything non compile-time constant. Leave it uninitialized and assign some memory to it in a function.

Comment: Thanx. I was doing this globally.

Answer (score 4):

Try initializing it in your `main()` function as you cannot initialize global variables with non-constant values or values that cannot be determined at compile time.

Alternatively you can declare it as

```
node dummy[27];
```

as a global variable instead of having to use malloc (if the size is constant).

Comment: This is not working if i declare it as global. Hence the error is coming. Please help. It is successfully declared in main, but not here